# JS script runs partially on heroku but fully locally (Django)

Tags: javascript, django, heroku

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
// get button by id
// document.getElementById('closedjs_$').style.display='none';
  var trips = document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="closedjs"]');

// trips = document.querySelectorAll('.closedjs')
  trips.forEach((element) => {
    element.style.display = 'none';
  });

// checking if current passengers >= max passengers so changing Join btn to Closed
  /*document.querySelectorAll('.joinleave').forEach((element) => {
    var route_id = element.dataset.id;
    var no_pass = parseFloat(document.querySelector(`#thepassengercounter_${route_id}`).innerHTML);
    var max_pass = parseFloat(document.querySelector(`#max_pass_${route_id}`).innerHTML);

    if (no_pass == max_pass) {
      if (element.innerHTML = "Join") {
        element.style.color = "#B22222";
        element.style.border = "1px solid #B22222";
        element.title = "Closed";
        element.innerHTML = "Closed";
      } else {
        element.title = "Leave";
        element.innerHTML = "Leave";
      }
    }
  });*/

  //  so as to not reload the page after joining or leaving a trip. It updates the innerHTML instantly
  //and then fetches as POST the route_id json page so as to update the DB

  document.querySelectorAll('.joinleave').forEach((element) => {
    element.onclick = () => {
      var route_id = element.dataset.id;

      fetch(`/route/${route_id}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((route) => {
          if (route.error) {
            console.log(route.error);
            alert(route.error);
          }

          var no_pass = parseFloat(
            document.querySelector(`#thepassengercounter_${route_id}`).innerHTML
          );
          var max_pass = route['no_pass'];
          var dist = route['dist'];
          var key_num = route['key_num'];
          var co2 = dist * 2.4 * 2;
          var fin = document.querySelector(`#fin_${route_id}`).innerHTML;
          var diff_p = max_pass - no_pass;

          //console.log(route_id);
          console.log('max passengers  ', max_pass);
          console.log('current passengers ', no_pass);
          console.log('is date or time passed? ', fin);
          console.log('diff pass ', diff_p);
          alert('presssed');

          //CODE EXECUTES UP TO HERE THE ALERT 'PRESSED' IS DISLAYED//

          //console.log(dist)
          //console.log(key_num)

          // checking if current passengers >= max passengers so not allowing joinining but only leaving
          if (no_pass < max_pass) {
            if (diff_p == 1) {
              if (element.title == 'Join') {
                element.style.color = '#B22222';
                element.style.border = '1px solid #B22222';
                element.title = 'Leave';
                element.innerHTML = 'Leave';
                document.querySelector(`#thepassengercounter_${route_id}`)
                  .innerHTML++;
                document.querySelector(`#closedjs_${route_id}`).style.display =
                  'block';

                alert(
                  'Congrats you just saved ' +
                  co2.toFixed(2) +
                  ' kg of CO2 by Carpooling'
                );
                join_route(route_id);
                est_cost(route_id);
              }
            } else if (element.title == 'Leave') {
              console.log(element);

              element.title = 'Join';
              element.innerHTML = 'Join';
              element.style.color = '#228B22';
              element.style.border = '1px solid  #228B22';
              document.querySelector(`#thepassengercounter_${route_id}`)
                .innerHTML--;
              leave_route(route_id);
              est_cost(route_id);
            }
          } else if (no_pass == max_pass) {
            if (fin === 'False') {
              if (element.title == 'Leave') {
                //console.log(element);

                element.title = 'Join';
                element.innerHTML = 'Join';
                element.style.color = '#228B22';
                element.style.border = '1px solid  #228B22';
                document.querySelector(`#thepassengercounter_${route_id}`)
                  .innerHTML--;
                leave_route(route_id);
                est_cost(route_id);
                document.querySelector(`#closedjs_${route_id}`).style.display =
                  'none';
                document.querySelector(`#closed_${route_id}`).style.display =
                  'none';
              }
            }

            /*       else {
                if(element.title == "Closed")
            {
                alert('Sorry, max number of passengers reached');

                element.style.color = "#B22222";
                element.style.border = "1px solid #B22222";
                element.title="Closed";
                element.innerHTML="Closed";
                //document.querySelector(`#thepassengercounter_${route_id}`).innerHTML++;
                //join_route(route_id);
                //est_cost(route_id);

            }*/
            /*            else if (element.title == "Leave"){
               console.log(element);


                element.title="Join";
                element.innerHTML="Join";
                element.style.color = "#228B22";
                element.style.border = "1px solid  #228B22";
                document.querySelector(`#thepassengercounter_${route_id}`).innerHTML--;
                leave_route(route_id);
                est_cost(route_id);

                }*/
          }
        });
    };
  });
});

/* function sort() {
  alert('sorting');
  document.querySelectorAll('.media').forEach((element) => {
    var route_id = element.dataset.id;
    var fin = element.dataset.fin;
    var fin_set = element.dataset.fin_set;
    console.log(
      route_id,
      'style',
      document.querySelector('.media').style.display
    );
    console.log(route_id, 'fin', fin);
    console.log(route_id, 'fin_set', fin_set);

    if (fin == 'True' || fin_set == 'True') {
      document.querySelector('.media').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      document.querySelector('.media').style.display = 'block';
    }
  });
} */

function join_route(route_id) {
  fetch(`/join/route/${route_id}`, {
    method: 'POST',
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data));
}

function leave_route(route_id) {
  fetch(`/leave/route/${route_id}`, {
    method: 'POST',
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data));
}

// Calculating the cost  per passenger depending on the number of passengers instantly on the page (changing innerHTML)
// The updating of the DB is being done in models by the cost method separately
function est_cost(route_id) {
  fetch(`/route/${route_id}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((route) => {
      if (route.error) {
        console.log(route.error);
        alert(route.error);
      }

      var origin = route['origin'];
      var destination = route['destination'];
      var init_cost = route['cost'];
      var max_pass = route['no_pass'];
      //console.log('the max passengers are', max_pass);
      //console.log(init_cost);
      var no_passengers = parseFloat(
        document.querySelector(`#thepassengercounter_${route_id}`).innerHTML
      );

      //console.log(no_passengers);
      if (no_passengers === 0) {
        var cost = init_cost;
        document.querySelector(`#costpp_${route_id}`).innerHTML = cost + '$';
      } else {
        var cost = init_cost / no_passengers;
        document.querySelector(`#costpp_${route_id}`).innerHTML = cost + '$';
      }
    });
}
```

Code executes up to the point that PRESSED alert is displayed.
It doesn't execute the `fetch` nor the `alert("Congrats you just saved "+(co2.toFixed(2))+' kg of CO2 by Carpooling')`.

No errors in console.
I can't understand how it can execute partially since it runs on the front end which means it has to do with the browser

Locally it runs smoothly.
What could be the prob?
It's a Django app.

Comment: Do you perhaps use an npm library that is excluded on prod dependencies?

Comment: No npm library . I suspect something with the fetch urls...

Comment: from the heroku log i can understand that it ignores from the fetch(`/join/route/${route_id}` the join path so it doesn't go through the appropriate view it just loads the same route. It just calls fetch(`/route/${route_id}` and it gives a GET instead of a POST

Comment: You probably have some error on the nested ifs. I am not saying that they are necessarily wrong, the logic could be complex, but they do feel a bit weird. Make sure to double check them. If the problem is there, then, there must be some difference between the code you are using locally and the one you deployed on Heroku. Redeploying will probably fix it.